# Definition of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

I have seen many books defining sequence as a function whose domain is N, the set of all natural numbers.

I really don't appreciate such 'less-general' definition.

Consider this:
**A sequence is an enumerated collection of objects.**

My Observations:
 1. Enumeration of a  collection implies the collection is indeed well defined. For otherwise: we really don't know what objects are qualifying to be its members, let alone their enumeration!

2. It includes the case of a finite sequence as well! Even the empty sequence can be defined now.

3.By definition of collection, repetitions of the elements are allowed.

Is this definition fine? Please suggest the mistakes.

The main motivation to do all this is to not see a sequence as a function. Rather it in itself is something different structure like set, group, e.t.c. By enumeration I mean listing all elements of a collection from left to right, one by one. Eg. The two sequences (1,2,3,...) and (2,1,3,4,5,...) are different because their elements are enumerated (arranged) in different ways. By countable collection I mean a denumerable or finite collection. However one can arrive to the usual definition from this. If there is something wrong in my definition, please help me to see that this does imply something absurd.

Comment: I prefer the book's definition.

Comment: Both 1 and 3 apply to the standard definition you quote, so they can't be reasons for preferring your (vague) definition instead. A function whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ must be well-defined, because it's a function. As for 3, certainly the standard definition does not say the function must be *injective*, so the standard definition allows "repetitions of elements." Consider the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: If ''enumeration ...implies the collection is indeed well defined'' means that we have a formal rule  that gives any element of the sequance than this definition cannot be used to define the real numbers as equivalence classes of sequances of rationals.

Comment: "enumerated" implies each element of the sequence is given a number - which numbers are you using to make the enumeration?

Comment: tl; dr: The usual definition of a sequence _is_ an enumerated (countably-infinite) collection of objects.

If $X$ is a non-empty set, a sequence in $X$ (i.e., function $f:\mathbf{N} \to X$) is _by definition_ a collection of ordered pairs
$$
(0, x),\quad
(1, x'),\quad
(2, x''),\quad
(3, x'''), \quad \dots
$$
with $x = f(0)$, $x' = f(1)$, etc. elements of $X$.

The first coordinate $k$ of each ordered pair serves to _define_ "enumeration" or "left-to-right ordering" in your definition. The second coordinate $f(k)$ is the "$k$th term", the number (or element of $X$) at position $k$.

Comment: Usefully, the definition does not rely on the terms being denoted using a particular ("left-to-right") planar notation. For instance, a computer might store a sequence non-serially in memory; a (countably-infinite!) collection of numbered raffle tickets might be thrown into a bin for drawing but still constitute a sequence because they retain their _abstract_ ordering. [...]

Comment: While it's true that finite sequences do not fit into this framework, the only necessary modification is to replace the natural numbers with an initial segment. Note further that there are reasons to distinguish sequences and finite sequences; particularly, limits make sense for sequences, but not for finite sequences. (This was closed seconds before I hit "post", hence the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed definition is based upon the concept of enumeration. Can you define enumeration in a way which is essencialy different from the definition of sequence? If not, then what's the problem with the usual definition of sequence? Otherwise, tell us what your definition is.

Comment: 'Enumeration' is in its literal meaning: an arrangement of elements of a countable collection.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar Now please define *arrangement* and *countable*. I'm particulary interested in your definition of *countable*.

Comment: @SanjeevKumar What this answer points out is that you want to replace the formal definition by an informal one that helps you understand the idea better. The informality is a good way to understand things, but when you try to make it precise (as the comment here asks you to) you are led right back to the formal definition as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is very problematic because the term "enumerated" is vague and you have not defined it.  The entire point of giving a definition like "function whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$" is to have a perfectly *precise* definition, in terms of other concepts that already have precise definitions.

Here is one way to salvage this definition which is pretty standard.  Define a sequence to be a function whose domain is either $\mathbb{N}$ or the set $\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m<n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Or more concisely, a sequence is a function whose domain is an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$ (an initial segment being a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $s\in S$ implies $n\in S$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\leq s$).

Comment: My favourite definition of sequence is: a function whose domain is an ordered set which is order isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},\leqslant)$.